# How I can Communicate between raspberry pi4 and multiple ZigBee (XBee) and sensors, RFID

Tags: sensor, wireless, raspberry-pi-os, rfid, xbee

**How I can Communication between raspberry pi4 and multiple ZigBee and sensors**

Hello,
I have one raspberry pi4 and 3 sensors (Temperature, Ventilation, Light) and one RFID how I can communicate between these sensors and RFID to transmit data wirelessly to the raspberry pi4 by using the ZigBee technique

The scheme that would like to accomplish is the following: Zigbee is connected to the raspberry that reads data from other Zigbee (which are connected to the sensors, RFID) for example, a temperature sensor).

And what is the Hardware I need for this connection ???

So, I would like to understand how to read the data of the various sensors using Zigbee.

Thank you for all

Comment: Have you tried the good old internet search? In this case for 'raspberry pi zigbee'?

Comment: yes I tried but I don't locate the right solution

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a hardware ZigBee "router", for example CC2530 / CC2531. Pay attention when you buy it: such devices may be sold pre-programmed, or with no software onboard, which means you'll have to program it yourself. You could use the GPIO library for programming but it's extra work.

In any case, once the dongle works, you get a serial port (CC2531 comes with a USB to UART converter, CC2530 must be connected to an existing UART), which you could use directly to send commands and read data from the sensors, or you could run `zigbee2mqtt` service and interact with your ZigBee devices via MQTT.